# ansible extend var list instead of override

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a role which defines a list of default properties in a `default/main.yml`

```
hdfs_namenode_properties:
  - { name: "dfs.permissions.superusergroup", value: "hadoop" }
  - { name: "dfs.namenode.name.dir", value: "/media/persistent0" }
```

But when i define my own `hdfs_namenode_properties` in my `site.yml`, then the defaults get overridden.

```
- name: set up cluster master
  hosts: masters
  vars:
    hdfs_namenode: "True"
    hdfs_namenode_properties:
      - { name: 'dfs.permissions.enabled', value: 'false' }
  roles:
    - azavea.hdfs
```

The template, which iterates over the properties list is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
{% for property in hdfs_namenode_properties -%}
  <property>
    <name>{{ property.name }}</name>
    <value>{{ property.value }}</value>
  </property>
{% endfor -%}
</configuration>
```

Is there a way to merge both lists?

Or to put it differently, how can i access the defaults so i can do something like

```
    hdfs_namenode_properties:
      "{{ <<default_namenode_properties>> 
          + { name: 'dfs.permissions.enabled', value: 'false' } 
      }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The var override is the default ansible behaviour. You can change this behaviour by changing `hash_behavior=merge` in your ansible.cfg file.

Source: [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Another way you could do this is to use the `default` jinja2 filter, so you would not define defaults in `role/yourrole/defaults` but directly in the template by doing something like (the template file is just an example, I'm not sure how the hdfs namenode conf is structured ):

```
# file: yourrole/templates/template.j2
[hdfs_namenode]
name: {{ hdfs_namenode_properties.name | default("dfs.permissions.superusergroup") }}
```

This way though you will always have to specify `hdfs_namenode_properties`, even as an empty dict ( `hdfs_namenode_properties: {}` )

Comment: I added the template to the question, because `hash_behaviour=merge` doesnt seem to work correctly (i added a `ansible.cfg` in the same dir as `site.yml`.

Comment: One more thing. The problem why hash_behaviour=merge wont work is because of the fact that i have lists, not dictionaries... or am i mistaken here?

Comment: No, it should not matter. Make sure you added `hash_behavior`, not `hash_behavioUr`

Comment: hmm. good spotting :). but neither works. and according to the ansible docs about hash_behavio(u)r: `This .. does not affect variables whose values are scalars (integers, strings) or arrays.` And i have an array here. So it doesnt apply :/

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct, you have a list :\! Then I think you either rename your variables to be single dicts, so instead of having an array of properties, have a single dict per property, that should merge the vars. Or you will have to re-structure your template to use "hardcoded" defaults :(